# Finding $\sup(a_n)$ and $\inf(a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I was trying to figure out $\inf(a_n)$ and $\sup(a_n)$ of the sequence defined by $a_n=\arctan(n^2-7n+13)$. Since $a_n$ is increasing for $n \geq 4$, and $\sup(a_n)$  cannot be $a_1, a_2, a_3$, I thought it was possible to apply the monotone theorem which states $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}a_n=\sup(a_n)$, so $\sup(a_n)$ should be $\pi/2$. Is it correct? What should I do to find $\inf(a_n)$?

Comment: It shouldn't be to difficult to compute the minimum of $n^2-7n+13$...

Comment: Yes,  you have a sequence going to infinity inside the arctan, so the sequence itself goes to $\pi 2$.   For infimum,  you actually have a minimum,  keep in mind an increasing sequence has a minimum at the first point!   So it's either the value at $n=4$ or $1,2,3$

Comment: @Alan that's right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct: $\sup\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}=\frac\pi2$ for that reason.

And $\inf\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}=\arctan(1)=\frac\pi4$, since $1$ is the smallest number of the form $n^2-7n+13$ ($n\in\Bbb N$). You can deduce this from the fact that$$n^2-7n+13=\left(n-\frac72\right)^2+\frac34$$and that $1=\left(\pm\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What if I don't notice that $n^2-7n+13$ can be written in that way? Is there another theorem that tells me how to find $inf(a_n)$, like I did for $sup(a_n)$?

Comment: There isn't always a magical theorem ready to drop from the sky to save us. But you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2-7n+13=\infty$ and that therefore the sequence $(n^2-7n+13)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a smallest value $\alpha$. So, $\inf\{\arctan(n^2-7n+13)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}=\arctan(\alpha)$. Just compute the first values of your sequence and detect the point at which it starts to grow. In this case, the first few values are $7,3,1,1,3,\ldots$